# How to manage large strings

Tags: string, performance, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

In a recent test of my ESP8266, I bumped into a memory limitation.

I have a simple http server that serves a json of the AP available around ESP8266.

```
function incoming_connection(conn, payload)
 conn:send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
 conn:send('Content-Type: application/json\n\n')
 conn:send(tableToJson1(currentAPs))
end
```

When I am at home, in Paris, AP list can be long, then I reach the payload max size.

In order to avoid this memory panic, I want to split my json in several chunks, then send one after the other.

I wrote this :

```
function splitString(str, maxlen)
  local t = {}
  for i=1, math.ceil(string.len(str)/maxlen) do
    t[i] = string.sub(str, (i-1)*maxlen+1, i*maxlen)
  end
  collectgarbage()
  return t
end
```

Then tried to test the function with this:

```
function genstr(len)
  local s=""
  for i=1,len do
    s=s.."x"
  end
  return s
end
for k,v in pairs(splitString(genstr(2000))) do print(v) end
```

Results of some test:

```
Length of generated string    +   Length of string chunks   +   Result
1500                          +   100                       +   OK
1500                          +   200                       +   OK
2000                          +   100                       +   Crashes after 8 lines
2000                          +   200                       +   Crashes after 4 lines
```

It seems that I reach a memory limit around 1500 bytes.

What would be your advice to go over this limit?

Comment: The headers should ideally be ending with `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem  is probably in `genstr`, not `splitString`.

Strings in Lua are immutable, in `genstr`, a new string is generated by each `s=s.."x"` in the loop.

```
  for i=1,len do
    s=s.."x"
  end
```

Instead, you could use the built-in [`string.rep`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.rep) (or, for more complicated cases, [`table.concat`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.concat)) to generate the test string.

Comment: Correct anwer, thak you

Comment: Another idea: write the resulting text on to flash first then send it.